# Custom ajax validation for text length doesn't work yii2

Tags: yii2

I am trying to check the length of the text entered but without success. It is working with the `required` rule because i get `the field is empty` error but not with mine validation. My custom rule works only on form submit. Also tried to enable ajax validation of the form but again nothing.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['author_id', 'title', 'review'], 'required'],
            [['author_id'], 'integer'],
            [['review'], 'string'],
            [['review'], function($attribute, $params){
                if(strlen($this->$attribute) < 10){
                    $this->addError($attribute, 'The review is too short! Minimum 10 symbols!');
                }
            }],
            [['review'], 'trim'],
            [['dt'], 'safe'],
            [['title'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['author_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['author_id' => 'id']],
            [['post_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => News::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['post_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }
```

My form:

```
<?php $form=\yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::begin([
                                'method' => 'post',
                                'options' => [
                                    'id' => 'textarea_' . $model->id . '',
                                    'class' => "textarea_review"
                                ],

                            ]) ?>

                            <input type="hidden" name="flag" value="1"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="model_id" value="<?= $model->id ?>"/>
                            <?= $form->field($model, 'review')->textarea(['id'=>'update_text_'.$model->id.''])->label(false) ?>
                            <?= $form->field($model, 'csrf_token')->hiddenInput(['value' => $session['token']])->label(false) ?>

                            <?= Html::button('Изпрати', ['onclick'=>'editComment('.$model->id.')', 'class'=>'btn btn-primary send-button']) ?>
                            <?php \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps skipping the inline validator and defining the `string` rule as follows is the best solution for you:

```
[['review'], 'string', 'max' => 10, 'message' =>  'The review is too short! Minimum 10 symbols!']
```

If you absolutelty need a custom validator, the second best option is to
use ajax validation.

If neither of the above suit you, the you won't get away with just writing php validation rules.
you need to provide client side script to implement the same validation logic in browser.

Either define a custom validator class and override [clientValidateAttribute()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#clientValidateAttribute()-detail)
or you may specify [clientValidate](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-inlinevalidator.html#$clientValidate-detail) property to the inline validator you're using in your custom rule.
Make sure you  follow the distinction between `yii\validators\InlineValidator`and `yii\validators\Validator` when reading trough the docs

Comment: Thank you! For now i will use the first option.It suits me for now :)

Answer (score 1):

For client-side validation you have to set `whenClient` property aswell, where you put javascript validation.

Here docs: [Client Side Validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$whenClient-detail)